# Does buying Battlefield 3 Premium Edition force you to use the 'Multiplayer Head Start Kit'?

Tags: pc, battlefield-3, origin

The [Battlefield 3 package available on Origin including both Battlefield 3 and a Battlefield 3 Premium upgrade](http://store.origin.com/store/ea/en_US/DisplayProductDetailsPage/productID.255751200) also includes the "Multiplayer Head Start Kit". This kit unlocks a variety of items in the game without you having to earn them.

I am wondering: If I purchase this version of the game, will I be **forced** into using this upgrade kit? (I absolutely do not want the kit.) The wording they use describing it in the package is as follows:

> You can also get a jump on the competition online with the Multiplayer Head Start Kit.

While this *suggests* that it is not mandatory, it is anything but definitive as to whether or not you are forced to use the kit.

Currently (Feb. 2013), this package is $60. Buying [Battlefield 3](http://store.origin.com/bf3) and [Battlefield 3 Premium](http://store.origin.com/store/ea/en_US/DisplayProductDetailsPage/productID.249982800) separately would be $90. So, it would be ideal to purchase this package so long as the kit is not forced upon me.

**Does anyone have a definitive answer as to whether or not using the kit is optional?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Multiplayer Head Start Kit is optional.**

---

Source: Bought the Premium Edition for a friend.